# Combinatorics confusion in formulas

Tags: combinatorics

I had this task a while ago; let's say I have 15 balls (5 in three different colors) and 3 identical boxes, in how many different ways can I place the balls in the boxes?

What I thought of was just following the formula for combinations with repetition like:

```
(n+k-1) choose k
```

but I got the wrong answer. Instead I was supposed to use something like:

```
(n+k-1) choose (k-1)
```

to calculate x1+x2+x3=15 but I don't understand the difference in these approches.

Sorry if I sound unclear somehow but I find it really hard to explain since I'm so confused as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the first box is arbitrary

Comment: Do you need to have an equal number of balls in the three identical boxes?

Comment: It depends what your $n$ and your $k$ are. If $n$ is balls and $k$ is boxes, then the second one is correct. You're choosing $k\mathord-1$ dividers between the boxes among the balls+dividers ($n+k-1$).

Comment: "5 identical balls (5 in three different colors)"? So how exactly are they identical?????

Comment: @barakmanos he wrote 15. But actually it would have sufficed to ask for 3 identical balls of each color

Comment: @barakmanos I was ignoring that little diversion... I was wondering if the "boxes" were going to turn into colors later.

Comment: @b00nheT: What makes you think that these two definitions are equivalent???

Comment: @Joffan: That comment was meant for the OP, not for you :)

Comment: @barakmanos the combination is uniquely determined by the color appearing in it. As there are only three boxes, having $3$ or $5$ balls of each color gives you the same number of combinations. Of course if you had strictly less than $3$ balls of some color, then the number of combinations would change.

Comment: @Joffan Yes, exactly. I forgot to specify, n is balls and k is boxes. My confusion really made my question blurry. Why do I want to choose k-1 though?

Comment: @Joffan Ah, that's a good explanation, I get what you mean. In which cases would I use the other way then? Is there some good rule of thumb or something I can take notice of?

Comment: You might possibly think of using the other way - with reversed $n$ and $k$ - if the number of "boxes" was more than the number of "balls"

Comment: @Joffan Alright, then I think I understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the mention of colors...

Imagine that, instead of $k$ boxes, you are putting separators in between the $n$ balls. At each location you can put a ball or a separator. But you don't need $k$ separators - only $k\mathord-1$ - to separate the balls into $k$ classes (=boxes). See [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).